# get is not defined in javascript- suspected jquery issue

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to write a Twitter bot (silly school assignment) that pulls songs from a Youtube channel's playlist and presents them. I think that I have all variables and functions called correctly, but when I run it from command prompt, I get an error saying that "get" (the Youtube API call is not defined. Any help is appreciated! Thanks in advance!

```
console.log('The bot is starting');

var Twit = require('twit');

var config = require('./config');
var T = new Twit(config);

var billboard = require("billboard-top-100").getChart;


var stream = T.stream('user');

stream.on('follow', followed);

function followed(eventMsg){
    var name = event.source.name;
    var screenName = event.source.screen_name;
    tweetIt();
}


function tweetEvent(eventMsg) {
  var replyTo = eventMsg.in_reply_to_screen_name;
  var text = eventMsg.text;
  var from = eventMsg.user.screen_name;
  if (replyTo == "HearBetterMusic") {
    var text = ("@" + from + tweetEventComments.pickAndPad());
    postTweet(text);
}
}


function tweetIt() {

    var playlistId = "UUknVpWR6m2Ijzkqo-aPXs_g",
        APIKey = "AIzaSyBDdHRVWmH3t_1sA0HSaK16IH_x-KsYaIo",
        baseURL = "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/";

    get(baseURL + "playlistItems?part=snippet&maxResults=50&playlistId=" + playlistId + "&key=" + APIKey, function(data) {

    var goodSongs = playlistItems.list;
    var goodSong = goodSongs[Math.floor(Math.random() * goodSongs.length)];

        // Do what you want with the data
    });

    var popSong = billboard[Math.floor(Math.random() * billboard.length)];
        console.log(popSong);

    var popArtist = billboard.artist[Math.floor(Math.random() * billboard.length)];
        console.log(popArtist);


    var tweet = {
    status: 'Dude! I cannot get away from' + popSong + '.' + popArtist + 'is the worst. Listen to' + goodSong + 'instead'
}

    T.post('statuses/update', tweet, tweeted);

function tweeted(err, data, response) {
    if (err) {
        console.log("Oh no! It didnt work");
    } else {
        console.log("It worked!");
    }
}
}

tweetIt();
setInterval(tweetIt, 1000*60*30);
```

Comment: run it from command prompt?

Comment: where is get() method defined? `get(....)` is not jQuery

Comment: get() is supposed to be used to call the Youtube API. I use it in the under function tweetIt()

Comment: It seems unlikely that the Youtube API would define a global function name like that. It's more likely to be `someVar.get`.

Comment: Should I just declare a variable like var getvideos.get? Sorry for my ineptitude; I'm just at my wit's end

Comment: Hey everybody, I fixed that problem, but now I have another

Comment: If you solved the issue, post a self answer and ask your new question in a separate question.

Answer (score 0):

I found a node module that solved this problem

```
function getMusic(){
const ypi = require('youtube-playlist-info');
ypi("AIzaSyBDdHRVWmH3t_1sA0HSaK16IH_x-KsYaIo", "UUknVpWR6m2Ijzkqo-aPXs_g").then(items => {
    [];
)
```